# convert pkcs1 signature to pkcs7 signature using nodejs

Tags: node.js, certificate, digital-signature, pkcs#7, pkcs

as you know, there is no pkcs7 sign in ios, so in backend with nodejs we must convert to pkcs7 for another service call which only accept pkcs7 and it's not in our company. in our sever we have that string which ios sign and certificate and we receive pkcs1 sign from ios , i use node-forge but it does not work
in backend I only have certificate and pkcs1 signature, which signs a string text,
how can I convert pkcs1 to pkcs7 signature using node js?
if there is other solution rather than nodejs, also may help

I tried node-forge, but it want private key which I don't have in server-side, I wanna do this without private key

Comment: I'm afraid your question does not make any sense. PKCS1 is a cryptographic standard defining RSA while PKCS7 defines CMS (Cryptographic Message Syntax).

Comment: yes i know، but our middleware only support pkcs7 and ios devices does not support it. and i should resolve it on server side

Comment: So you have an ios device and a back-end component running on NodeJS? Could you rephrase your question and explain a bit more how those work together? The string text is signed on the iOS device, right? Using which library, and how?

Comment: i update my question. it's exactly as you said, but i don't know what happen in ios , i only receive final signature in pkcs1 format in a post request

Comment: Could you provide a sample?

Comment: you mean example of my pkcs1 signature? and a valid pkcs 7?

Comment: An example of a PKCS1 signature generated from your code.

Comment: let pkcs1 = `mwakqstwSik0w5dao49VfP78zHsg9jA5ZrqsgmHSEiOgUM6lCoqJJnB/4MfdVU95yhioPkNfjlU9
  Kr6rowtaYZN1OLtVVY3Ta5lUIT+aOt/v4UdZthY3IMuRF+r7xY50Cdh/f7/1YEOG0F0GbgcQkT+F
  y8+Hm0ysEaZagZC2T5a5g6j+Hjz1zJ545ycBYC182gyTanZ8GmvfDGfBZAuMCFdKJ64eVkJJjxcs
  buzr1I3IoJh5ymBMSY1GDqPc3HQpR0q/cSMA7JZSmtCVCoooZnC+hmh1PcsdVIbNFUOU9GB9/nBh
  P2HCvgTG5sQz6KaTDnjDnkQE+jR0Yt50WGyFsw==`

Comment: Which cipher are you using to generate this ? Can you also share the source code ?

Comment: the pkcs1 generated in ios devices ,  and i only receive it in request , don't know anything about their code